# Eclipse Jersey Alternative IDE Solution

Tags: rest, eclipse, jdbc

**Context:** I want to create a REST client-server app with a database, Tomcat 10 and JDBC? I am looking for other IDE stacks to work with instead of Eclipse Jersey as I was currently investigating since I am not very familiar with it.

**Problem:** To make the issue clearer, my problem is I am new to this type of development and the learning curve of Eclipse Jersey in combination with the rest of the technology stack seems intimidating. Is there any solutions to kinda get my 'feet wet' that are easy for complete newcomers in REST service implementation using JAX-RS or another implementation?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need some more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. E.g. what don't you like with EJ and what would you consider "better"?

Comment: @Izzy I will make an edit to make the question clearer.

Comment: Thanks Nick – that indeed makes it clear now! Best luck with good recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

Jersey is a JAX-RS implementation.  Another popular JAX-RS implementation is CXF, but Jersey is the "reference implementation", if that means anything to you.  I've implemented services with both, but recently I've only been using Jersey.

You don't have to use a JAX-RS implementation.  You can use plain Spring MVC which has similar semantics.  That is also a popular choice, but I personally have only been using JAX-RS Jersey, and implementing REST services is almost all that I do.

None of this technically has anything to do with what web server or database you use.  Those are SpringBoot issues, not JAX-RS or REST issues.

Comment: I heard about some of my colleagues reference SpringBoot. Hmmm I see. As for the web server and database, I am completely new to this type of development so I wouldn't know, just decided to give as many details as possible just in case.